# Sever communicating with client and vice versa

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there any way how to communicate between those two?

Lets say i have a server.
Someone uploads a file , the server process the file and find that its incorrect and send event to the client. The client catch the event and does some DOM manipulation displaying fancy styled error message.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Yes, this happens all the time, and the internet wouldn't function if it didn't. It's what AJAX is for. Google REST or RESTful applications.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** - of course this is possible.  Since you have tagged your question with javascript and nodeJS, I'll show you one example with javascript for the server, i.e. nodeJS.

It uses callback functions for routes.  This allows you to do just what you describe, build logic into any given request.  Below is a standard route request from a user to login, you can see below that there is a simple 'if' statement which will execute code if 'something went wrong' and return a message to the user. Take a look:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.send({error : 'something went wrong :('}); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.send({success:'success'});
        });
    })(req, res, next);
})
```